# Uniquess of solution of the differential equation $ y'' -2 \tan(x) y'- y=0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, contest-math

So this is problem from a competitive examination.
The given differential equation is:

$$ y''- 2\tan(x)y' -y=0 $$ with $y(0)=1,$ $y'(0)=1$ and $y(\frac{\pi}{3}) = 2\left( 1+ \frac{\pi}{3} \right)  $ on the interval $ \left( \frac{- \pi}{2
}, \frac{\pi}{2}  \right) $

It says that this has a unique solution, but I can not conclude how.
I know that we have a unique solution for the Differential equation for $y(0)=y'(0)=1$, but what about the condition  $y(\frac{\pi}{3}) = 2\left( 1+ \frac{\pi}{3} \right)  $.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The ODE has coefficients that are smooth where they are defined, so if there is a solution with these boundary conditions, it is unique. Or was your question about the *existence* of a solution with the overdetermined 3 boundary conditions?

Comment: @LutzLehmann, Yes you are right that if the soultion exists then it is unique. But what I want to know is that how can we say that there is a solution $y$ with takes the given value at $\frac{\pi}{3}$? Yes I am worried about the existence of the solution with the overdetermined $3$ boundary conditions.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I have edited the question and corrected the discrepancy

Comment: In this version you get a slight reduction in the number of terms if you substitute $y(x)=\cos(x)z(x)$. But that might also be a dead-end.

Comment: If you just want assurance, $y=\sec(x) \,(1+x)$ should provide that. The third condition is redundant. To try to solve, use $y'=uy$ or read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm–Liouville_theory. This one is $(\cos^2(x)\,y')'=\cos^2(x)\,y$

Comment: Fixed link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory

Answer (score 1):

Computing an "integrating factor" for the first two terms, substitute $z(x)=\cos(x)y(x)$. Then
\begin{align}
z'(x)&=\cos(x)y'(x)-\sin(x)y(x)\\
z''(x)&=\cos(x)y''(x)-2\sin(x)y'(x)-\cos(x)y(x)\\
&=\cos(x)[y''(x)-2\tan(x)y'(x)-y(x)]\\
&=0
\end{align}
so that $z$ is any linear function. Since $z(0)=y'(0)$ and $z'(0)=y'(0)$, the linear function to the given initial values is $z(x)=1+x$.